# How to create a launcher icon for anaconda navigator in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, launcher, anaconda

Generally, there is not an icon for anaconda navigator in Linux. that's why every time I used the terminal to open anaconda navigator. And then if I close the terminal somehow then the total project got closed.

Answer (score 1):

To create a launcher icon, first create a `.desktop` file. You should call it `Anaconda.desktop`.
Inside the file, type:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Anaconda
Exec= anaconda executable path here
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

Then do `chmod +x Anaconda.desktop` so you can execute it. You should be able to execute it properly. Hope this helps